# Error creating bean 'kafkaMessageChannelBinder' defined org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.KafkaBinderConfiguration:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, saga

Getting this error
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaMessageChannelBinder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.KafkaBinderConfiguration: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:326) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:215) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.bindFunctionToDestinations(FunctionConfiguration.java:443) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.afterPropertiesSet(FunctionConfiguration.java:401) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.epam.incubation.practice.saga.OrchestratorApplication.main(OrchestratorApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.computeParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:111) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:87) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:289) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:328) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:513) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:292) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:107) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1421) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1342) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1324) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1291) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.getResolvableType(DependencyDescriptor.java:314) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.checkGenericTypeMatch(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:77) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:69) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:147) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:806) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1488) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.support.management.ManageableLifecycle
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
... 81 common frames omitted

2021-02-05 09:53:02.420  WARN 23316 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'functionInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaMessageChannelBinder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.KafkaBinderConfiguration: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle
2021-02-05 09:53:02.420  INFO 23316 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-02-05 09:53:02.435  INFO 23316 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-05 09:53:02.436 ERROR 23316 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'functionInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaMessageChannelBinder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.KafkaBinderConfiguration: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at com.epam.incubation.practice.saga.OrchestratorApplication.main(OrchestratorApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaMessageChannelBinder' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.config.KafkaBinderConfiguration: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:326) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:215) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.bindFunctionToDestinations(FunctionConfiguration.java:443) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.afterPropertiesSet(FunctionConfiguration.java:401) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/support/management/ManageableLifecycle
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.computeParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:111) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:87) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:289) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:328) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:513) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:292) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:107) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1421) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1342) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1324) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1291) ~[spring-core-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.getResolvableType(DependencyDescriptor.java:314) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.checkGenericTypeMatch(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:77) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:69) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:147) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:806) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:748) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1488) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.support.management.ManageableLifecycle
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]

Service class

@Service
public class OrchestratorService {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("payment")
private WebClient paymentClient;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("inventory")
private WebClient inventoryClient;

public Mono<OrchestratorResponseDTO> orderProduct(final OrchestratorRequestDTO requestDTO) {
    Workflow orderWorkflow = this.getOrderWorkflow(requestDTO);
    return Flux.fromStream(() -> orderWorkflow.getSteps().stream()).flatMap(WorkflowStep::process)
            .handle(((aBoolean, synchronousSink) -> {
                if (aBoolean)
                    synchronousSink.next(true);
                else
                    synchronousSink.error(new WorkflowException("create order failed!"));
            })).then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> getResponseDTO(requestDTO, OrderStatus.ORDER_COMPLETED)))
            .onErrorResume(ex -> this.revertOrder(orderWorkflow, requestDTO));

} 

private Mono<OrchestratorResponseDTO> revertOrder(final Workflow workflow, final OrchestratorRequestDTO requestDTO){
    return Flux.fromStream(() -> workflow.getSteps().stream())
            .filter(wf -> wf.getStatus().equals(WorkflowStepStatus.COMPLETE))
            .flatMap(WorkflowStep::revert)
            .retry(3)
            .then(Mono.just(this.getResponseDTO(requestDTO, OrderStatus.ORDER_CANCELLED)));
}

private Workflow getOrderWorkflow(OrchestratorRequestDTO requestDTO){
    WorkflowStep paymentStep = new PaymentStep(this.paymentClient, this.getPaymentRequestDTO(requestDTO));
    WorkflowStep inventoryStep = new InventoryStep(this.inventoryClient, this.getInventoryRequestDTO(requestDTO));
    return new OrderWorkflow(List.of(paymentStep, inventoryStep));
}
```

}

and this is my config class

@Configuration
public class OrchestratorConfig {

```
@Autowired
private OrchestratorService orchestratorService;

@Bean
public Function<Flux<OrchestratorRequestDTO>, Flux<OrchestratorResponseDTO>> processor() {
    return flux -> flux.flatMap(dto -> this.orchestratorService.orderProduct(dto))
            .doOnNext(dto -> System.out.println("Status : " + dto.getStatus()));
}
```

}

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?